# Pushertc running error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed a WebRTC application developed in rails from this source: https://github.com/tokafish/pushertc  and when I try to run it locally it shows me this error:

```
home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:17:in `rescue in split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Can somebody try this app and tell me what I am missing?

```
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:14:in `split'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pusher-0.14.1/lib/pusher/client.rb:53:in `url='
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config/initializers/pusher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /home/arsim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /home/arsim/Downloads/pushertc-master/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please post a full traceback if you would like to get some proper answers.
Besides, the repo you provided is a final result of author's blog post mentioned in the repo description. You would learn much more if you could write the code yourself along with the mentioned blog post.

Comment: I editet the post, but can u try this app and see what happens